# Notification icon and balloon messages in c# cross-platform

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, mono, gtk3

I'm going to develop a desktop application which is a sort of background service listening for events. The requirements for this application are:

- tray icon in background always visible
- show up notifications on desktop when an event occurs (like receive an email such as, you will notify with a popup)

The main problem is that the application must run under Windows,Mac and Linux.
I decided to develop the main business logic in .NET Core, but I have a few problems about the front-end part; using `Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon` it's easy, but obviously this solution isn't valid for other platforms.
So, I found `GtkSharp` project, in particular the `StatusIcon` object seems to do exactly what I need, except for the notification part. What I need is a sort of balloon info which is already part of `Windows.Forms.NotifyIcon`, but not in Gtk. Does anyone know if there is a library or a component that allow me to achieve my requirements for a cross-platform context?

**[UPDATE]**
I asked directly in GtkSharp channel and they told me that is not possible do what I need with GtkSharp (moreover StatusIcon is deprecated and removed from GTK 4).

I found another interesting possible way, seems that Electron framework support all my requirements. Is a different approch, but it covers all what I need and works well on MacOs,Windows and Linux.

Comment: Look at Xamarin and Xamarin.Forms

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski I can't find anything that I need in Xamarin.Forms